# Seaborn Align twinx and x Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, x-axis

I am trying to align X axis with its twin but I'm not finding a way to do it.

Here is my code

```
# Initialize the figure
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))

# Adding a title
plt.title(f'Client Retention Quarters: Monthly Cohorts', fontsize = 14)

# Creating the heatmap
sns.heatmap(retention, annot = True,vmin = 0, vmax =30,cmap="flare", fmt='g')
plt.ylabel('Cohort Quarter')
plt.xlabel('')
plt.yticks( rotation='360')

#Twinx
ax2 = plt.twiny()
ax2.set_xticks(range(0,len(x2)))
ax2.set_xticklabels(labels=x2)
ax2.spines['top'].set_position(('axes', -0.10))
plt.show()
```

And here is the output:

[image: Cohort]

I want to align the percentages with the x ticks.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below updated code. See if this works. Note that I have used random data for `retention` and `x2`. Basically, the main change it to get the `xlim()`s for both axes and then adjust it (see lambda f) so that the ticks align. Finally use set_major_locator() to fix the points. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
retention = np.random.rand(10, 12) ##My random data
# Initialize the figure
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))

# Adding a title
plt.title(f'Client Retention Quarters: Monthly Cohorts', fontsize = 14)

# Creating the heatmap
ax=sns.heatmap(retention, annot = True,vmin = 0, vmax =30,cmap="flare", fmt='g') ## Note I am assigning to ax
plt.ylabel('Cohort Quarter')
plt.xlabel('')
plt.yticks( rotation='360')

x2 = np.around(np.linspace(1, 25, 12),2)
#Twinx
ax2 = ax.twiny()
#ax2.set_xticks(range(0,len(x2))) ## Commented as not required
#ax2.set_xticklabels(labels=x2) ## Commented as not required

## New code here ##
import matplotlib.ticker
l = ax.get_xlim()
l2 = ax2.get_xlim()
f = lambda y : l2[0]+(y-l[0])/(l[1]-l[0])*(l2[1]-l2[0]) ##Add delta to each tick
ticks = f(ax.get_xticks())
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator(ticks)) ##Set the ticks

ax2.spines['top'].set_position(('axes', -0.10))
plt.show()
```

[image]